# Subscrible to Observable in TypeScript method with multiple possible return type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a TS method defined with the signature

```
getById(id: string): Observable<IResponseMessage> | Observable<IStrategy> {
}
```

But when I'm trying to subscribe the above method like this

```
this.strategyService.getById(id)
            .subscribe(success => {

            });
```

The compile time error occur that says
`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

I don't know how to subscribe to method with multiple possible return type. Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> getById(id: string): Observable | Observable {

I would make it

```
getById(id: string): Observable<IResponseMessage | IStrategy> {
```

Then you get the same `subscribe` and you discriminate inside the subscribe between ResposneMessage and Strategy using type guards : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html